# Need help configuring Apache Shiro for authentication separation (multiple REST APIs)

Tags: java, spring, rest, authentication, shiro

I am building a web application using an AngularJS front-end and a Spring Boot REST back-end (they are running on separate servers i.e. port 3000 and port 8443). The back-end is supposed to connect to multiple external services (with separate authentications) and provide endpoints for the front-end to use.

For security, I decided to use Apache Shiro. For simplicity, I will pretend there are just 2 external services (ES1 and ES2).

I have created 2 x `AuthorizingRealm` which connect to the respective external services and attempt authentication using the provided tokens.

In the `doGetAuthenticationInfo` method, if the login is successful, I return a `SimpleAuthenticationInfo` with the principal, credentials and the name of the realm.

In the `doGetAuthorizationInfo` method, I check the realm name of the principal and, if it checks out, I return a `SimpleAuthorizationInfo` with the role "USER" and a permission (e.g. ES1_permitted).

I also extended the `UsernamePasswordToken` class for each realm to separate usage even more (through the `supports` method).

In a configuration class, I create a bean for a `DefaultWebSecurityManager` that uses my two realms and a bean for the Shiro filter. 
I added 4 filters:

- anon `AnonymousFilter`
- perm `PermissionsAuthorizationFilter`
- es1 `ES1Filter`
- es2 `ES2Filter`

My filter chain looks something like:

```
/api/es1/login  -> anon
/api/es1/**     -> es1, perms[ES1_permitted]
/api/es2/login  -> anon
/api/es2/**     -> es2, perms[ES2_permitted]
/**             -> anon
```

Somehow, when I served front-end and back-end from the same server (no CORS), it seemed to work. However, now that CORS is an issue, I can't seem to get this to work as expected.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this complete separation of authentication/authorization? I am willing to switch to Spring Security if it can be done there as well.

PS: I am using the Java API, not configuration files (spring xml or shiro.ini).